# Length of each string argument

Tags: c, arguments, args

Recently I've started to get a little bit into the `stdarg.h` functions, because I want to have something similar to `printf` but instead of writing to the console I want to return it as a string.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
char *write(const char *format, ...)
{
    // init
    va_list arg;
    char *string;

    va_start (arg, format);
    vsprintf (string, format, arg);

    // done
    va_end (arg);
    return string;
}
```

Now the problem is, that `string` has not reserved memory and that's where I need help with a way to fix this function as I have not found any solution yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: One option would be to use `vsnprintf()` with n=0, because that will return the number of characters that would have been written (without actually writing anything). Then you can allocate a buffer based on that, and call vsnprintf again, but with the correct n

Comment: _Then you can allocate a buffer based on that,_: be aware that you need to allocate one by more that what was returned by `vsnprintf` for the NUL terminator.

Comment: Why don't you just use `sprintf`?

Comment: Which is why i wrote 'based on' @Jabberwocky ;-). I would hope that OP actually reads the vsnprintf documentation before blindly implementing anything. But yes, there's a pitfall there, because n is supposed to be the size of the buffer (including '\0'), whereas the return value is the number of characters without '\0'

Comment: @FelixG this is one of the common problems people ask about here

Comment: @klutt he want's the function to return a pointer to the generated string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `snprintf(NULL, 0` to check how long buffer you need. Then allocate memory. Then print to the string.

```
char *my_write(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, format);

    // remember to have a separate va_list for each v*print function
    va_list va2;
    va_copy(va2, va);
    const int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, va2);
    va_end(va2);

    char *string = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(*string));
    if (string != NULL) {
       vsprintf(string, format, va);
    }
    va_end(va);

    return string;
}
```

As suggested by @IanAbbott in comments you can invoke `va_start` twice, which seems to nicely simplify the code:

```
char *my_write(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, format);
    const int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, va);
    va_end(va);

    char *string = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(*string));
    if (string == NULL) {
       return NULL;
    }

    va_start(va, format);
    vsprintf(string, format, va);
    va_end(va);

    return string;
}
```

On platforms with with glibc you can also use `vasprintf`. Note that the name `write` is already used by [posix write() function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), I suggest to use a different name. With `vasprintf` GNU extension it becomes just:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
char *write2(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, format);
    char *string;
    const int err = vasprintf(&string, format, va);
    va_end(va);
    if (err == -1) {
          return NULL;
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Why is that?:/* remember to have a separate va_list for each v*print function */ 

I reworked my function based on FelixG's answer [ by just adding an int length = vsnprintf(string, 0, format, arg); and then malloc the string with length+1] and it seems like it works just fine. Just curious about those little bits that I mostly overlook

Comment: Because the v*printf function consumes the va_list, you can't just reuse it afterwards. I didn't mention the va_copy in my comment, but it's definitely necessary, so this post is indeed the correct and complete answer

Comment: After you use `va_list` in one of `v*printf` calls, you should only `va_end` it. You can't do anything else with it. So to use `va_list` twice, you have to `va_copy` it. `seems like it works just fine` It's undefined behavior.

Comment: welp, thanks for this quick advice I was looking for :)

Comment: After `va_start(va, format);` and `va_end(va);` it is allowable to re-use the `va` variable with another call to `va_start(va, format);`, so there shouldn't be any need for `va2` and `va_copy(va2, va);` in this code.

Comment: @IanAbbott Hmmm, `v*printf()` appears to "invoke the `va_arg` macro" (C17dr footnote 292) and "Each invocation of the `va_arg` macro modifies `ap` so that the values of successive arguments are returned in turn" § 7.16.1.1 2, so it appears a `va_copy()` is obliged.  Interesting.

Comment: KamilCuk, any particular reason for `if (err < 0)` and not `if (err != -1)` given [these functions will return -1](https://linux.die.net/man/3/vasprintf)?

Comment: No, no particular reason, just some habits I guess. I guess I have that fear in the back of my head of imaginary non-existent implementations that could return any other negative number except `-1`.

Comment: @chux The sequence I mean is something like `va_start(va, format);` `vsnprintf(NULL, format, va);` `va_end(va);` `va_start(va, format);` `vsprintf(string, format, va);` `va_end(va);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for the detail.