# vsnprintf fails after realloc

Tags: c, variadic-functions, realloc

I got this code (below) thats basically an snprintf function but a bit slower, meaning it also handles buffer size with malloc/realloc.

The code works how it should up to the point where the realloc changes the address (when the string gets larger and larger over time)... If that happens, the output is completely wrong.

```
bool write_str(char **str, const char *format, ...)
{
    // va arg stuff
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, format);
    // remember to have a separate va_list for each v*print function, because v*print consumes the function
    // but in this case it actually doesn't need it
    size_t len = vsnprintf(0, 0, format, argp);
    if(*str)
    {
        *str = realloc(*str, len + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        *str = malloc(len + 1);
        **str = 0;
    }
    if(!*str)
    {
        return false;
    }
    vsnprintf(*str, len, format, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    (*str)[len] = 0;
    return true;
}
```

And that's how you would use the function.

```
char *str = 0;
write_str(&str, "That is how %d use it\n", 2);
```

edit: Comments come from here [Length of each string argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61011481/11223349)

Comment: You can use va_list only once. Have a look into va_copy.

Comment: `/ remember to have a separate va_list for each v*print function, because v*print consumes the function` Maybe you should read the comment, too

Comment: I tried that and did not improve... unless I did it wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found what was causing **my** problem. Kind of silly--should've posted the code I really used.

I mainly used this function to append a string to itslef, repeatedly. But the thing is, realloc can change the address of the string, so the passed address isn't the same anymore, resulting in a garbage output.

```
char *str = 0;
write_str(&str, "string");
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    write_str(&str, "%s%s", str, "string"); // the right str argument may change address, don't use it like that!
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

edit: I now got a function that works. It turned out that you do need the `va_end`.

```
bool append_str(char **str, char *format, ...)
{
    if(!str || !format) return false;
    
    bool result = false;
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, format);
    
    // get memory
    int len_app = vsnprintf(0, 0, format, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    int len_str = 0;
    if(*str)
    {
        len_str = strlen(*str);
    }
    *str = realloc(*str, len_str + len_app + 1);
    
    // append
    va_start(argp);
    if(*str)
    {
        if(vsnprintf(&(*str)[len_str], len_app + 1, format, argp) >= 0)
        {
            // successful
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // encoding error
            free(*str);
            *str = 0;
        }
    }
    va_end(argp);
    
    return result;
}
```

And an example of how to use it:

```
char *str = 0;
bool success = true;
success &= append_str(&str, "Hello world!!%d\n", 231);
success &= append_str(&str, "Hello world!!%d\n", 231);
success &= append_str(&str, "Hello world!!%d\n", 231);
success &= append_str(&str, "Hello world!!%d\n", 231);
success &= append_str(&str, "Hello world!!%d\n", 231);
if(success)
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
else
{
    printf("failed to append string.\n");
}
return 0;
```

Comment: So your misstake was in a part of the code  that you didn't show us. So, baically your answer us useless, too. BTW: even without the realloc(), it is always illegal to s[n]printf() a string onto itself.

Comment: @wildplasser I now edited the solution and I hope it suits your taste

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int write_str(char **str, const char *format, ...)
{
    // va arg stuff
    int len;
    va_list argp;

    va_start(argp, format);

    len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, argp);
    // Remember to read the comments (or remove them)
    // remember to have a separate va_list for each v*print function
    // , because v*print consumes the function arguments
    // but in this case it actually doesn't *use* them -- IT DOES consume them!!!!!

    va_end(argp);

    *str = realloc(*str, len + 1);

    if(!*str) return -1;

    va_start(argp, format);
    vsnprintf(*str, len, format, argp);
    va_end(argp);

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{

char *str = NULL;
write_str(&str, "That is how %d use it\n", 2);
puts(str);

write_str(&str, "That is how again %d use it\n", 666);
puts(str);

return 0;
}
```

---

Some notes:

- argp is **consumed** by `vsnprintf()` ;  you need to copy or re-initialise it if you use it twice
- `vsnprintf()` returns a **signed** type (-1 is also a valid return value: check that, too)
- `realloc()` is smart enough to understand the first call (when the first argument is NULL), no need to handle this separately

Comment: hm thanks, I'll try that (I already I think did that). The comments come from here https://stackoverflow.com/q/61011481/11223349

Comment: Why non-standard C `ssize_t` with `ssize_t len;` and not `int len;` to match the type returned by `int vsnprintf()`?

Comment: Sure using `va_start(argp, format);` twice is OK?

Comment: Im not sure, I think it *should* work (va_start is always the first call to the varargs-thingy, so it *should* (re)initialise) WRT ssize_t: you are correct.

Comment: No, you cannot use va_start(dst) twice with the same pointer; you need to use va_copy to a secondary pointer that you can consume; and each va_start(dst) or va_copy(dst, src) must be paired with a matching va_end(dst), otherwise there's memory leakage or corruption: depending on platform's calling conventions, va_start may allocate dynamic memory (on the heap or on the stack, to create a "regularized" frame, e.g. for call parameters passed in different sets of native registers, depending also on their value type) and va_end will free that memory.